# Automated testing with Robot framework : Switching beetween windows that open on the same browser

Tags: robotframework, switching

can someone help me to switch between windows that do not open as pop-up windows, but on the same browser ?

Switch Window  locator=NEW gives me an error that it has the same index
Select Window gives me an error that there is no keyword

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the similar issue while handling the print preview page.
Give a sleep time of 2-3 seconds and then use the same keyword.
It should work.

Else :Create a keyword in ***Keywords*** section

Print window

```
switch window    NEW
```

Then use the following wait option in ***Testcases***

wait until keyword succeeds |  20seconds |   2seconds |   Print window