# Automated testing with Robot framework : RE Switching beetween windows that open on the same browser

Tags: robotframework, switching

Following the question : [Automated testing with Robot framework : Switching beetween windows that open on the same browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989674/automated-testing-with-robot-framework-switching-beetween-windows-that-open-on) a second issue arises.

How do I make it stay on the new tab if the original and the new tab have the same title.

I click the element, a new tab opens, then it switches to the original tab.

If I take out the Switch Window keyword, it stays on the new tab but it doesn't find the next element, I imagine because it is looking in the original tab.

Click Element   //*[@id="id1"]

Sleep           3 seconds

Switch Window   TAb 2

Wait Until Page Contains Element           //*[@id="id2"]

Click Element           //*[@id="id3"]

Sleep                   20 seconds

Is it possible to solve this ?

Comment: https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Switch%20Window ... Use handle as locator instead of tab name ..  https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Window%20Handles

Answer (score 0):

You can try using window handles and switch to the particular tab

Identify and switch to first window
@{list1}  get window handles
Switch Window  ${list1}[1]  -- this will switch to the latest tab opened